# Is it a good idea to have a separate copy of the socket.io.js file instead of relying on the file served by a socket.io app?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Consider this scenario:

1. Socket.io app went down (or restarted) for some reason and took about 2 seconds before it started again (considering the use of production manager app ie: `PM2`).
2. Within the 3 second down time a client tried to request the client `socket.io.js` script (`localhost:xxxx/socket.io/socket.io.js`) and resulted as a failed request (error `500`, `404`, or `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`) before the server got started again.
3. After the three second downtime the server file is available again.

So now i have no other way but to inform the user to refresh to resume real time transactions.

I cannot retry to reconnect to the socket.io server because i do not have the client script.

But if it is served somewhere else, perhaps at the same `dir` where `jQuery` is, i could just listen if io is available again by writing a simple retry function that fires for every few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's a good idea to use the version served by Socket.IO, as you'll have guaranteed compatibility.  However, as long as you stay on top of making sure you deploy the right versions, it's perfectly fine to host that file somewhere else.  In fact, it's even preferred since you're taking the static load off your application servers and putting it elsewhere.

An easy way to do what you want is to configure Nginx or similar to cache that file and serve a stale copy when the upstream server (your Node.js with Socket.IO server) is down.  https://serverfault.com/q/357541/52951

Comment: thanks for the answer! I'll try this one. One more thing, do you know if I can also do this in IIS?

Comment: @javiniar.leonard I'd imagine so.  I haven't used IIS in years so I couldn't give you any specifics.